# Android - java set global context to another class

Tags: java, android, activerecord, android-context

The first problem is i have java class with 500 lines. That will so bad, so i want to split them. I found solution in another stackoverflow thread that, we can pass main class context to another class.

```
//main class
Public class Main{
 @Override
 Public void onCreate(Bundle inst)
 {  
  Super.onCreate(inst);
  ClassB bclass = new ClassB(this);
  bclass.setLayout();
 }
}

//B class
Public class ClassB{
 Activity act1;
 Public ClassB(Activity act)
 {
  act1 = act;
 }
 Public void setLayout()
 {
  this.act1.setContentView(R.layout.lay);
 }
}
```

Okay, thats work. But how to make act1 be our main context? so every time i want call setContentView from ClassB i don't need to use act1 again

Edit 1:
 What i hope is, i want to make act1 as default context for ClassB. So when i call setContentView from ClassB, its directly called to Main.setContentView

Because if i just call setContentView from  ClassB, i wi get NullPointerException. Its make a sense since ClassB have no context

Comment: @LAD unfortunately, that is now what i looking for. in my code, i want to call setContentView from ClassB without typing this.act1.setContentView().

Comment: It's probably cleaner to leave activity functions to be acted on either as a function or on a weak reference to an `Activity`. Having a second class with a member field `Activity` or `Context` is a very easy move towards having memory leak issues.

Comment: @Bryan Dormaier. so you want to say this.act1.setContentView is good already?

Comment: I don't think you need to call `this`, though. I think `act1.setContentView();` should work.

Comment: I'm saying keeping a reference to your `Activity` in another class can lead to memory issues down the road. It is cleaner to maintain separation by having your Activity encompass any code having to do with UI - such as `setContentView()` and have your non UI logic in a separate class like a Presenter. Your secondary class can communicate via interface which will have a smaller footprint than storing a reference to an `Activity`

Comment: If you are set on maintaining a link to your Activity you should hold it using a `WeakReference` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing this. There are ways to reduce lines of a single java class instead of keeping UI references in other classes or rendering UI by other classes.  You can encapsulate your business logic(Not UI) in other classes which can improve the readability of your code or in your case, if you have multiple Activities which have similar behavior, you can create a base abstract activity class and put all the base code to it.